cxf-codegen map multiple .wsdl files with gradle
Currenly I use this code:
def wsdlDir = file('path/to/wsdl')

wsdlDir.eachFile { wsdlFile ->
    tasks.register("wsdlFile.name", Wsdl2Java) {
        toolOptions {
            wsdl.set(wsdlFile.toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString())
        }
    }
}

It works, but creating a separate task for each file in a loop doesn't seem an optimal way to do it. I saw examples in Maven to specify a dir with .wsdl files, is there anything similar for gradle?

I'm the author of the Gradle plugin. No, that functionality does not exist. It was an intentional design to choice to omit that when creating the Gradle plugin. The reasoning is because, as shown in your example, it can be accomplished directly in your build file if needed or desired or in some convention plugin. That logic can then be extracted to buildSrc to cleanup your build file.
I'm not opposed to providing that functionality in the plugin. There just have not been any sizeable requests for it: https://github.com/ciscoo/cxf-codegen-gradle/issues
